# Destroy uiimage view with smoke effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiimageview

I want to destroy an image view with smoke effect. Is there any to do it.

I am already using the emitter effect to show smoke.

First I hide the `UIImageView` and then perform the smoke emitter effect . But it is not giving proper effect.

Comment: can you show us some what exetly you want effect attach image

Comment: I need a solution that gives an effect like image is converted in smoke.

Comment: any feedback? about

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use some trick to making this look better and possible. I suggest to create one overlay image that look like 60% to 70% transparent with smoke effect and create that overlay in Photoshop.

Then when you want to apply smoke effect then make this transparent image to overlay on your main image and merge this both image in to one like create an image programmatically that looks perfect and easy as well.

Here following i just create an demo project : https://github.com/nitingohel/NGSmokeOverlay

it's output:

[image]

Comment: thank , I will try this